# Angular component not implementing interface in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

I guess I didn't fully understand `interfaces` in Typescript, so here is my example.

I've got this interface:

```js
export interface AdComponent{
    data: any;
}
```

My two components both implementing the `AdComponent` interface with required property `data`:

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AdComponent } from '../ad.component';

@Component({
  template: `
    <div class="job-ad">
      <h4>{{ data.headline }}</h4>

      {{ data.body }}
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [],
})
export class HeroJobAdComponent implements AdComponent {
  @Input() data: any;
}
```

```js
import { Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AdComponent } from '../ad.component';

@Component({
  template: `
    <div class="hero-profile">
      <h3>Featured Hero Profile</h3>
      <h4>{{data.name}}</h4>

      <p>{{data.bio}}</p>

      <strong>Hire this hero today!</strong>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [],
})
export class HeroProfileComponent implements AdComponent {
  @Input() data: any;
}
```

Then in a `service` I want to create a registry of the components:

```js
  private registry = new Map<string, AdComponent>();


  private initRegistry(){

    //Type error here: HeroJobAdComponent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AdComponent'.
    this.registry.set("herojob", HeroJobAdComponent);
```

Here I get a type error:

```
Argument of type 'typeof HeroJobAdComponent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AdComponent'.
  Property 'data' is missing in type 'typeof HeroJobAdComponent' but required in type 'AdComponent'.ts(2345)
```

Why this isn't working?
What I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Should registry contain the *classes*? Currently it's a map to *instances*. Your [mre] doesn't need any of the Angular stuff: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqAWBLAdgc2gbwLAChr+gBMwAXMALmjGQE8BuXAX112AHtkIToSk0YAvNGQBTAO7QAsmAAOAHi4AnFKgA0cPqgB8ACgCUDHLl4qIAOggiSOgEQBrETRvqEKg8c3nL1+4+fDxDRV9dxwgA.

Comment: *I guess I didn't fully understand interfaces in Typescript,* actually it looks like you have a misunderstanding of how generic types works. as a hint: `this.registry.set("herojob", new HeroJobAdComponent());` would work (assuming you have empty constructor there). Java equivalent of what you did would be `Map<String,AdComponent> map; map.put("whatever",HeroJobAdComponent.class)`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I was trying to have a map containing the _classes_.  So now the map is `Map<string, Type<AdComponent>>()` using `Type` from `@angular/core`. I should have explained I needed the classes to use `ComponentFactoryResolver`.